# Execute Package Utility (dtexecui) not installed after installing SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017, dtexec

I was not able to find Execute Package Utility (dtexecui) after installing SQL Server 2017. Was not able to find any standalone installer from Microsoft to install it as well. Will any one please guide me on installing it to run my SSIS Packages?

Answer (score 22):

I've just found the exact same issue.

I did check my path for DTExec and found it installed as part of SQL Server Management Studio 18 (18.3.1) in the following location along with DTExecUI:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn
```

Of course your install location may vary.

For reference, I found the program in different locations based on different version of Sql Server Management Studio

SQL Server MS 2014

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\
```

SQL Server MS 17

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\
```

(Edit) One final note, in my instance the dtsx packages didn't have any default application and i had to add the registry entries required to pass the parameters:  This was mine:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IntegrationServices.Package.140\Shell]
@="Open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IntegrationServices.Package.140\Shell\Open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IntegrationServices.Package.140\Shell\Open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\SSIS\\150\\Binn\\DtExecUI.exe\" /F \"%L\""
```

Once that was in place, using the default process to associate files with the application, dtsx files opened on the server with the correct parameters.

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem isn't from Window now offering compression on everything. Seems to be a good idea, generally, to decompress all directories and files in the SQL Server folders. If there are two blue arrows pointing toward each other on the folders in explorer, the files are compressed. You can decompress looking in the properties.

Comment: Since I only need it to execute local packages, I added the location to my PATH variable, restarted windows terminal and now is working from the powershell line

Answer (score 1):

It seems the dtexecui Desktop App not installed with SQL server 2019, as an standalone desktop application! if you want this desktop app install SQL server 2017 or a lower version!

In SQL Server 2019, you should use SSMS to run an stored package (either stored on SSIS or file system). Also you have to connect to a running SSIS for this purpose at first. After that if you want to run an existing package which is saved on file system, you should import it before running it.

[Running DTExecUI from in SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmMxt.png)

Comment: Thanks! I installed the latest version of SSMS 2017 and then could easily run my locally-stored .dtsx files.

Comment: For Management Studio 20, the correct path is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 20\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\160\Binn